# PHP - Regular Expression Multiple Option Parsing

Tags: php, regex, parsing, templates

I am very bad at regular expressions and thus need some help:

I need to find multiple options with one regular expression in a content:

1. `{{ Value }}` - Always
2. `{{ Value | Value 2 }}` - Optional second part - | Value 2
3. `{{ Value | Value 2(Value3) }}` - Optional third part - (Value3)

Rule: Spaces are allowed before or after value

What I got is this but it doesn't work for all three needs and optional:

```
/\{{(.*)|(.*)}}/siU
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/\{{2}\s*?(.+)(?:\s*?\|\s*?(.+)\s*?(?:\(\s*?(.+)\s*?\))?)?\s*?\}{2}/isU
```

Beautify this by yourself please.

- `\{{2}` is an opening curly bracket (`\{`), exactly two of them (`{2}`).
- `\s*?` is a whitespace (`\s`), zero or more times (`*`) and as many as possible (`?` in ungreedy mode)
- `(.+)` is any character (`.`), one or more times (`+`)
- `(?:x)?` is a subexpression x that is not added to the results (`?:`) and that must occur never or once (trailing `?`). Here this is used to make the "Value 2" part optional.
- `\s*?\|\s*?` are as many whitespaces as found, a vertical bar and more whitespaces (if found).
- That is followed by another optional subexpression for "Value 3".
- `\(\s*?(.+)\s*?\)` is an opening parenthesis (`\(`), as many whitespaces as found (`\s*?` again), the actual content (at least one character, `.+`), more whitespaces and a closing parenthesis.
- `\}{2}` is the closing curly bracket, and exactly two of them as well.

Answer (score 0):

my approach

```
/\{\{[\s\W]*((\w+)([\s\W]*\|[\s\W]*([\w]+)([\s\W]*\([\s\W]*(\w+)[\s\W]*\)[\s\W]*){0,1}){0,1})[\s\W]*\}\}/
```